# How to make react native multiline TextInput scroll automatically as user types?

Tags: react-native

I have a multiline TextInput, where I don't specify the numberOfLines, immediately inside a View.

If the user is typing long content in the TextInput such that it grows to a height that's longer than the screen, I want the TextInput to automatically scroll down so that the user's typing is always visible.

How do I do this?

I believe this is similar to [this past SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135133/react-native-programmatically-scrolling-multiline-textinput), but the best solution there points to a library, `react-native-input-scroll-view`, that was archived in 2021.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, my TextInput wasn't scrolling because I think it could grow vertically forever. When I implemented a maxHeight, it led to the proper scrolling behavior.

This got a little tricky because the maxHeight of the input should be different depending on whether the keyboard is showing. `useSafeAreaInsets` from `react-native-safe-area-context` helped me get a value for the additional height I needed to account for at the bottom of the screen, while [this SO question (second response)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587006/how-to-get-a-height-of-a-keyboard-in-react-native) helped me reliably and easily get the keyboard's height when it opened or closed.